# Transforming JSON with XSLT using SaxonEE and Python

Tags: java, python, json, xslt, saxon

I am attempting to write a Python script that transforms JSON to a text file (CSV) with XSLT.

With *saxon-ee-10.5.jar*, I can successfully perform the desired transformation by running the following command (Windows 10):

```
java -cp saxon-ee-10.5.jar com.saxonica.Transform -it -xsl:styling.xslt -o:result.csv
```

How can I achieve the same result by using Python? I have been trying with Saxon-EE/C, but I am not sure if what I want to happen is possible.

Here is an example of what I have tried so far. My XSLT already defines an `$in` parameter for the *initial.json* file, but the `PyXslt30Processor.apply_templates_returning_file()` seems to require a call to `PyXslt30Processor.set_initial_match_selection()`, of which I am not sure if non-XML files can be passed.

```python
from saxonc import PySaxonProcessor
with PySaxonProcessor(license=True) as proc:
  xslt30proc = proc.new_xslt30_processor()
  xslt30proc.set_initial_match_selection(file_name='initial.json')
  content = xslt30proc.apply_templates_returning_file(
    stylesheet_file='styling.xslt', 
    output_file='result.csv'
  )
  print(content)
```

Is what I want to accomplish possible with Saxon-EE/C, or should I try techniques of calling Java from Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `call_template...` instead of apply-templates, e.g. https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/saxonc.html#PyXslt30Processor-call_template_returning_file with

```
xslt30proc.call_template_returning_file(None, stylesheet_file='styling.xslt', 
    output_file='result.csv'
  )
```

Using `None` as the template name should be identical to using `-it` on the command line, i.e. start by calling the template named `xsl:initial-template`.

Don't use `xslt30proc.set_initial_match_selection` in that case.

It might, however, help, to set `xslt30proc.set_cwd('.')` before the `call_template_returning_file` call.